# PHP SQL Update array

Tags: php, html, mysql

I originally was satisfied with the following in order to update row 1 and row 2 to the same value (status=1)

```
if ($_POST){
    $sql ="UPDATE table SET  status = 1,
            WHERE id IN (1,2 );";
    db()->query($sql);

    if(db()->query($sql)){
        echo "<b>Good</b>";
    } 
    else{
        echo "<b>No Good</b>";
    }
}
```

But now I want to update with different values, ie- row 1 to status 1, row 2 to status 2, and row 3 to  status 3.

Off the bat, I know I need to 
1. Use an array and loop through it three times.
2. pass in the array value into the $sql

I figure it would be something like this but I am still learning PHP..

```
$array_id = array(1, 2, 3);
$array_status = array(1, 2, 3);

if ($_POST){
    $sql ="UPDATE table SET  status = $array_status
            WHERE id = $array_id;";
    db()->query($sql);

    if(db()->query($sql)){
        echo "<b>Update Successful</b>";
    } 
    else{
        echo "<b>Update Unsuccessful</b>";
    }
}
```

How would I go about making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really explain why you need that, so

try1(childish): set status = id

```
"UPDATE table SET status = id"
```

It's a bad practice, and only you could understand what those numbers are. Plus if id is auto-increment, status will be auto-increment too, you will have a duplicate column. If status has only 3 values posible, you should not do this.

try2(basic): do 3 updates, or actually, do as many as you need with a for

```
if ($_POST){

$status = 1;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
$sql ="UPDATE table
       SET status = $status
       WHERE id = $i;";
db()->query($sql);

$status++;
}
```

A better way bacause you have more control over the status. Of course the second try is irrelevant if you have only that 3 values. This one assumes you will change the $status variable inside the for loop, in concordance with the $i (id)

try3(mature): set one or 2 arrays with the concordance between id and status, so that either $arr[$id] will have the value of status and the key will be the id, or $arr1[$i] will have the value of id, and $arr2[$i] will have the value of status

the example will have only one array(also called map, because you map a value based on another value)

```
if ($_POST){

$status_array = array(1 => 1,2 => 2,3 => 3);


for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
$sql ="UPDATE table
       SET status = $status_array[$i]
       WHERE id = $i;";
db()->query($sql);
}
```

Also, this works because the array is consistent. If you do not have an consistent array you should either work with 2 arrays, or try a foreach with key->value instead of for

Comment: I think it's not the authors intention to change the status for each id just by `++`. He said that this would be an *example*. Actually, I think he's looking for a way to change the status of each ID *independently* to the other `ID`s and its statuses.

Comment: was editing post. he didn't really explain what he needed, i provided him with 3 solutions from the easiest possible to a decent one.

Comment: also, i explained my example is for this case, you can change $status being a function of $i, as you'd wish.

Comment: Sorry folks, I should have been more clear.  It is not incrementing, it just happened to work out that way.  It could be, id 1 to status 3, id 45 to status 50, and row 39 to status 74.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the following code:

```
$theArray = array("1" => "1","2" => "2","3" => "3"); // The scheme is ID => Status

$errorMsg = false; // Our default assumption is that no error occured

foreach($theArray as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET status =".$value." WHERE id = ".$key;

    if(!db() -> query($sql)) { // Execute the query and check whether it failed
        $errorMsg = "Query for ID ".$key." failed.";
        break; // When the query failed we exit the loop and echo the error message
    }
}

if($errorMsg) { // If an error occured (errorMsg is no longer false) we echo it here
    echo $errorMsg;
}
```

Basically you do just create one array `$theArray`, which contains `key => value` pairs of the `ID`s and the `status`es you want to give them. Afterwards, you loop through this array, execute the `db() -> query()` for each `key => value` pair and check whether it failed or not. If a `query` failed, you `break` the loop and output the error message.

---

**Advantages:**

- Instead of using two arrays (`$array_id`, `$array_status`) I do use only one [associative array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) `$theArray`. The advantage here is that you only have *one* instead of two arrays and that you can extend the number of rows you'd like to change without changing your code. Just extend the array.
- The array `$theArray` does *not* need to be in a chronological order and you can give each `ID` independently of the other `ID`s a `status`.
- You are executing the `db() -> query($sql)` in your code two times. This is *not* very efficient and redundant. Instead you can execute the command only once and immediately check whether it failed or not based on its `return value` inside the `if()`.
- The `errorMsg` I am creating in the code let you know which `query` failed so it gives you a more detailed information for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the arrays using a [for loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and exec a query for each one (Radu Vlad answer), or you can build a long query and execute it once, something like this:

```
if ($_POST){
    $sql = ""; // Blank string
    $len = count($array_id); // Number of iterations
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) { // Enter the loop
        $sql .= "UPDATE 
                  table
                SET
                  status = {$array_status[$i]}
                WHERE id = {$array_id[$i]};"; // Append the query
    }
    db()->query($sql);
    
    if(db()->query($sql)){
        echo "<b>Update Successful</b>";
    } 
    else{
        echo "<b>Update Unsuccessful</b>";
    }
}
```

When the val of `$i` is 0, then `$array_id[$i]` will print the first element, when `$i` is 1, `$array_id[$i]` will print the second element, and so on.

Using `.=` you append text to a string. By the end of the loop, `$sql` will be a string with 3 queries ('UPDATE ... SET ...; UPDATE ... SET ...; UPDATE ... SET ...;').

Not sure if it's the best way, though. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If yow want the `status` to be equal to the `id`, do this (single query):

```
UPDATE table SET status=id WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

Of course you can use some math, like:

```
UPDATE table SET status=(id+1)*2 WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update multiple rows (in single query) using the INSERT syntax, you can do this:

```
REPLACE table(id,status) VALUES(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)
```

Notice that `id` must be Primary Key or Unique, otherwise the REPLACE will insert a new row.
Notice also that REPLACE isn't SQL standard, and works only in MySQL.