# SQL update with PHP arrays

Tags: php, sql, adodb

Let's say i have and array like this

```
$array= Array('id'=>'3', 'name'=>'NAME', 'age'=>'12');
```

Keys from this array are name of columns in table and values are value of columns which i need to update.
I want to update the table based on keys and values. 
I am using ADODB
Please help me

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945476/php-sql-update-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884284/simple-update-mysql-table-from-php-array

Comment: Did ANY of the below answers worked man?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET ";
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
   $sql .= $key . " = " . $value . ", "; 
}

$sql = trim($sql, ' '); // first trim last space
$sql = trim($sql, ','); // then trim trailing and prefixing commas
```

and of course the `WHERE` clause:

```
$sql .= " WHERE condition = value";
```

you will get the string:

```
UPDATE table SET id = 3, name = NAME, age = 12 WHERE condition = value
```

**L.E:** You might need to add apostrophes to strings so I have to change my code to something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET ";
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
   if(is_numeric($value))
      $sql .= $key . " = " . $value . ", "; 
   else
      $sql .= $key . " = " . "'" . $value . "'" . ", "; 
}

$sql = trim($sql, ' '); // first trim last space
$sql = trim($sql, ','); // then trim trailing and prefixing commas

$sql .= " WHERE condition = value";
```

which will produce this:

```
UPDATE table SET id = 3, name = 'NAME', age = 12 WHERE condition = value
```

**L.E 2:** If you want the id column in your condition, the code becomes this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET ";
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
   if($key == 'id'){
      $sql_condition = " WHERE " . $key . " = " . $value;
      continue;
   }
   if(is_numeric($value))
      $sql .= $key . " = " . $value . ", "; 
   else
      $sql .= $key . " = " . "'" . $value . "'" . ", "; 
}

$sql = trim($sql, ' '); // first trim last space
$sql = trim($sql, ','); // then trim trailing and prefixing commas

$sql .= $sql_condition;
```

which will produce this result:

```
UPDATE table SET name = 'NAME', age = 12 WHERE id = 3
```

Hope this helps! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($update_array as $key => $testimonials) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($testimonials->name);
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($testimonials->content);
    $id = intval($testimonials->id);

    $sql = "UPDATE testimonials SET name='$name', content='$content' WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7884331/3793639

Other sources to check.
[PHP SQL Update array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945476/php-sql-update-array) and [Simple UPDATE MySQl table from php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884284/simple-update-mysql-table-from-php-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this for achieving that:

```
foreach($values as $value) {
  if(!key_exists($value, $item)) {
    return false;
  }

    $table->{$value} = $items[$value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the key index is always id and that adodb can use named placeholders you could do this:

```
$array = Array('id'=>'3', 'name'=>'NAME', 'age'=>'12');
$set = array();
$data = array();
while(list($key,$value)=each($array)) {
    $data[':'.$key] = $value;
    if($key!='id') {
        $set[] = $key . ' = :' . $key;
        // if no placeholders use $set[] = $key . " = '" . database_escape_function($value) . "'";
    }
}
$sql = "UPDATE table SET ".implode($set, ',')." WHERE id=:id";

//$data is now Array(':id'=>'3', ':name'=>'NAME', ':age'=>'12');
//$sql is now  "UPDATE table SET name=:name, age=:age WHERE id=:id";

$stmt = $DB->Prepare($sql);
$stmt = $DB->Execute($stmt, $data);
```

Comment: [prone to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example)

Answer (score -2):

This is probably the shortest and easiest for you, you can also use something like this to achieve it:

```php
$array = Array('id'=>'3', 'name'=>'NAME', 'age'=>'12');

$sql = "UPDATE table SET ";

$sql .= implode(', ', array_map(function($key, $value){
    return is_numeric($value) ? "{$key} = {$value}" : "{$key} = '". mysql_real_escape_string($value). "'";
}, array_keys($array), $array));

$sql .= " WHERE id = 123";



// Result : UPDATE table SET id = 3, name = 'NAME', age = 12 WHERE id = 123
```

Comment: You shouldn't post such a code, there is already enough SQL injections in the world

Comment: @YourCommonSense you can use `mysql_real_escape_string` as i update my code.

Comment: Nope, I can not

Comment: @BhavikHirani: see: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: @Luuk Yes i already add `mysql_real_escape_string` for string value, and numeric value don't need `mysql_real_escape_string`